# Long Running Process in Openshift - like sunspot

Tags: sunspot-rails, openshift, sunspot-solr

I know there are quite a few openshift fan out there and the list of feature that openshift give you I dont blame them too

so this question is for those guys I have `solr` full text search engine running on the openshift

Now the I using `sunspot_rails` to connect to `solr` to create indexes

all work well for sometime and all the indexes get create appropriately but we experience that after a while the `connection` to solr keeping getting lost

So I'm assuming that openshift doesnot allow long running process like `solr` to run and would kill after some period of time

am I correct in my believe

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nohup` to launch your script with post_start_ and post_stop_ scripts in .openshift\actionhooks

[Redhat openshift - Cron Runtime - Is there a default time for how long cron executes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218013/redhat-openshift-cron-runtime-is-there-a-default-time-for-how-long-cron-exec) shows how to do it with cron.

Comment: I can do that but question was whether the openshift guys actually monitor a process and kill it as already said in Q I'm starting the solr using nohup in deploy hooks but I find that the solr process disappearing after something from my process list