# Redhat openshift - Cron Runtime - Is there a default time for how long cron executes

Tags: cron, redhat, openshift

Cron on Redhat openshift is cancelled by SIGTERM after some minutes.

Is there a default timeout on how long cron tasks can execute?
If yes, how to get long running tasks working?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, There is apparently a default timeout of **5 min** on top level script for cron tasks execution on Redhat openshift.

The solution is to use "nohup" to get long running tasks working.

For ex:

File .openshift/cron/minutely/task1 -

```
nohup /path-to/some-other-script > $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/logfile 2>&1 &
```